# StudentID is an integer between 1000 and 999,999. Can not be null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following problem:

Create a new table in the practice schema call course. it has the following properties.

`CourseRegNumber`-- this will be a whole number between 1000 and 9999. This column will automatically increase by 1 each time. This will be the primary key.

`StudentID`-- whole number between 1000 and 999,999. Can not be null.

What I am having trouble with is writing the StudentID part. 
This is what I have `StudentID INT (1000,1) NOT NULL`. 
However I have to have something between INT and (1000,1) and I am not sure what goes there.

Comment: Please post your `CREATE TABLE` statement for us to review.

Comment: Are you looking for [check constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

Comment: Use Practice;
Create Table Course(CourseRegNumber INT IDENTITY(1000,1)PRIMARY KEY,
StudentID INT (1000,1) NOT NULL, RegisteredFlag TINYINT NULL,
ModifiedDate DATETIME2 NULL);


And no I am not checking constraints

Comment: Have you even [**looked** once at the official MSDN documentation??](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx). It is quite clear on what those values are .....

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a job for a [check constraint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```sql
Create Table practice.course (
    CourseRegNumber int identity(1000, 1) not null primary key,
    StudentId int not null,
    Constraint CK_CourseRegNumber Check (
        CourseRegNumber >= 1000 and 
        CourseRegNumber < 10000
    ),
    Constraint CK_StudentId Check (StudentId >= 1000 and StudentId < 1000000)
);
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fcc38)</kbd>**